# Debug Android app when not attached

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to fix a seemingly random crash in my app. The problem is, I've left it connected to my debugger in Android Studio for hours and it won't crash. In fact, it only crashes when the app is not in the forefront. I'm pretty sure it has to be related to my broadcast receiver, but I can't reproduce it at will.

Is there any way I can recover the logcat from the crash if I attach the debugger after a crash? Is there an easy way to log to a persistent file?

Comment: You should still see the logcat of the crash when you connect the device to your computer, it doesn't have to be connected at the time of the crash for you to receive the output.

Comment: **"Is there an easy way to log to a persistent file?"** : The logcat buffer *IS* persistent...well, partially persistent - at least up to a point as it is circular and will be overwritten eventually. As mentioned by @Egor, if you connect your device immediately after a crash, you should be able to see the most recent logcat entries. There is something slightly ominous about your crash not happening when connected and being debugged - it suggests you have a "race" condition due to multi-threading or asynchronous code which doesn't appear with single-step debugging.

Comment: The reason I thought the logcat was not persistent turns out to be because of ongoing issues I'm having with Android Studio and lag in the logcat. I didn't see the error messages because even though the error occurred before I started debugging, it appeared in the logcat _after_ the messages about updating the package and connecting the debugger to the process.

Comment: As far as the randomness of my error, it turns out that it was taking place in two parts of my code. The first was in the on boot receiver, which fires somewhere in my boot order (which given how often I install and uninstall things is semi-random) and in a legacy method that I didn't even realize was still there, but only fired in obscure circumstances. The actual error turned out to be that I was trying to get a column from a cursor that did not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egor had the answer. I thought my error was not showing in my logcat because either things were showing up out of order in my logcat or Android Studio was showing me things that happened over half an hour ago. Basically, I connected the debugger and saw that the first thing in the logcat was about updating the app and connecting the debugger, and so assumed that I had missed whatever came before. The error was about twenty lines down from there.

Answer (score 0):

Create bug report on your phone and send it to your email. After that you could search for your app package crash information.

You can make bug report under Developers options in phones settings or you can enable Power menu bug report (more convenient) under the same Developers options section.